# Advice on combining and adding values in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

I am quite new to Python, and I have currently been doing this manually in Microsoft excel.

I would like to identify duplicate columns and then add together the total votes for each column using Python. For example:

| Person | Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Variable 3 | Vote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 710 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 750 |

In the table `0,1,1` would have total 1710 votes and `1,0,0` would have 750. So, I am trying to combine the rows with duplicate values and add together the total number of votes, i.e., person 1 and person 2 in this example have voted for a project with the same characteristics so their final vote would equal 1710.

I was hoping that the final table would look like this:

| Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Variable 3 | Vote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1710 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 750 |

I am struggling with this one any any advice would be greatly appreciated.

All the best,
Tom.

Comment: pandas groupby() with .sum()

Comment: If you don't want the overhead of pandas then you could accumulate the votes in a dictionary, keyed off the tuple of Variable 1/2/3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a pandas dataframe (You can use [`pd.read_excel('file_name')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to pull in your data as a pandas dataframe), you can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by the 3 variable columns, then sum() to get the sum of the vote column:

```
df.groupby(['Variable 1', 'Variable 2', 'Variable 3'], as_index=False)['Vote'].sum()

   Variable 1  Variable 2  Variable 3  Vote
0           0           1           1  1710
1           1           0           0   750
```